# Java EhCache : How to keep old data when new data is unavailable

Tags: java, persistence, ehcache, rollback

I'm using EhCache 2.10.0 and I have a cache that is refreshed every 30 minutes. After this time, I want to keep datas in my cache when my method throws an exception.

This is my cache configuration :

```
<cache name="cache"
       eternal="false"
       maxElementsInMemory="1"
       overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="1800">
</cache>
```

This is my method summarized :

```
@Cacheable(value="cache")
public List<Element> getListeElements() throws MyException {
    [...]
    if(foo) {throw new MyException();
    [...]
}
```

Is it possible ?

My project run with JDK 7